# masm byte range

Tags: masm

I am having a hard time understanding this and hopefully someone can correct me on it. A BYTE is defined as 0 - 2^7  ?  which would be 128, which is 8 bits, correct? But that cant be correct because I am now storing a value of 255 into a BYTE? Any kick in the right direction would be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An **unsigned** byte is 2^8 = 256, but if you have to store the sign, the you need to sacrify a bit, then you have +- 2^7 = -127 + 128.

Comment: +1: I may say "byte" like an American, but I've accidentally come to think of them as "octets". I think this mental and written notation clarifies thinking about them; this is not my own invention: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octet_(computing)

Comment: yeah, but please don't say Mega-Octet and Giga-Octet!